# cache in the browser -- tools and theory

Tags: browser, caching

My current tools include YSlow, Fiddler and the new PageSpeed.

My questions is:  is there a better tool for finding out exactly WHAT the browser is caching, WHEN it's caching it, and WHY other assets are not caching.

A brain-dead simple explanation of HTTP headers, vis-a-vis caching would also be useful.  The more gotchas the better, such as "Greenwich Mean Time" *is* what the browser relies on, etc.

Answer (score 1):

www.fiddler2.com/redir/?id=httpperf explains how WinINET (the HTTP stack behind Internet Explorer) performs caching.  See also http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Perf/AboutVary.asp

Answer (score 0):

At the risk of self-promotion I've written [Supercharging Javascript in PHP](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/05/supercharging-javascript.html) and [Supercharging CSS in PHP](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/05/supercharging-css-in-php.html), which deal specifically with caching (on the client and the server) including appropriate HTTP headers like far-futures Expires and ETag to minimize external HTTP requests.

Answer (score 0):

the browser doesn't have a concept of local time. It simply sends the servers own last-modified date back at it as the value of if-modified-since and lets the server decide how much time has passed.

I just use the webdeveloper toolbar addon for firefox and check the 'response headers' manually. It's usually pretty obvious when something is/isn't being cache since the browser renders incrementally. There is a way to force a fake connection speed as well, but I can't remember how. Slow the rate to 14.4k and you'll really see where your caching is working.