# Caching jQuery REST Ajax Response in all the Browsers

Tags: jquery, performance, web-services, cross-browser

How to cache the jQuery Ajax REST API Response of JSON Objects in all the Browsers, mainly in Firefox Mozilla, Chrome, IE8

Comment: Send the appropriate caching headers. Related: [cache in the browser -- tools and theory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/975836)

Comment: The Related Link is not have the Correct Answer and also i need sample and clean notes on how to implement it.

Comment: has any one found any one solution ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I get your question right...
but this could help: https://github.com/kpuputti/JSONCache

Comment: Thanks! checkout my question which i have updated clearly for a better understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is imho no cross-browser solution to force caching the API requests using javascript. Yo will need an alternative approach as @Gotschi recommended.

The best, and most common way is to send cacing headers on your API as @Pekka 웃 recommended.

You have to set the [cache-control](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9) header on your API responses:

Example (Force 1h caching = 3600 Seconds):

```
Cache-Control: max-age=3600, private
```

The private property indicates that all or part of the response message is intended for a single user and MUST NOT be cached by a shared cache.

If you are using PHP, you may send the headers (Before any output like echo) like this:

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: max-age=3600, private');
```

You may also use your apache configuration or an .htaccess file:

```
Header set Cache-Control "Cache-Control: max-age=3600, private"
```

Ensure to not use `{cache:false}` in [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Nice but My Case is different after the page is loaded, Ajax will be called some click event

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. Mostly ajax requests are fired after an user interaction like a click. That has no impact to my answer. The best would be if you provide an example.

Comment: So you are saying there is no option to do caching in javascript ?

Comment: Right. You have to store the data manually using cookies, localstore etc. as @Gotschi already recommended. If you have control over the API, you should use the standard compliant headers.